# strange regex experasion

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I've got a quick harmless question...
what does this expression mean:
`/(^|[\s\0])/g`

Comment: What you think? what part is unclear for you?

Comment: Which part of the regex do you not understand? What is "strange" about it?

Comment: Paste it in regex101.com and find out :-)

Comment: The ^| what does it mean?

Comment: `|` is logical OR in regex and makes your regex engine to match `^` that is an anchor for matching the start of the string  or `[\s\0]` that is a alphabetical character or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it out on regex101.com, looking on the right side: [image]

Hope you can see this ok and can grok it.